# The existence of the product of a morphism from the quotient of an equivalence relation.

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, universal-property

In [*Topologies et Faisceaux* by **Demazure**](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~patrick.polo/SGA3/Exp4-23mai11.pdf), Proposition 3.3.4. p.180 (or p.192 in the linked pdf), states the following:

> Let $R$ be a universal effective relation in $X$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Z$ be a compatible morphism with $R$, hence factorizing through $g:X/R\rightarrow Z$. TFAE.
>   **(i).** $g$ is a monomorphism.
>   **(ii).** $R$ is the equivalence relation defined by $f$.

Then it proceeds to  prove that **(ii)** implies **(i)** by way of Proposition 2.5 (the converse is indeed obvious). However, to use that proposition, it is necessary that the fibre product $X/R\times_ZX/R$ exists.

So my question is:

> Why does the product $X/R\times_ZX/R$ exist, or does it necessarily exist?

It seems that this should follow from the universal effective hypothesis, or the universal effective "epicity" of $g$, but I cannot deduce the existence of the product in question from the given hypotheses.

Any help or reference is appreciated.

**P.S.** My last question turned out to be answered by the linked, newer version, so this time I checked that this is not covered in the pdf either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer, after some tries, follows.

(Please forgive the ugly-looking commutative diagrams; I wish I can use tikz here.)

We wan to show that if $R$ is the relation defined by $f$, then $g$ is a monomorphism.

Consider the diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&&&A\\
&&&&\downdownarrows\\
R&\rightrightarrows&X&\xrightarrow{p}&X/R\\
&&&f\searrow&\ \downarrow g\\
&&&&Z
\end{array}
$$
with $A\rightrightarrows X/R\xrightarrow{g}Z$ equal.

By hypotheses, $R$ is a universal effective equivalence relation, so $p$ is a universal effective epimorphism, and hence we can form two fibre products:
$$(X\times_{X/R}A),\,(X\times_{X/R}A)'.$$
Now consider the diagram:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&&(X\times_{X/R}A)\times_A(X\times_{X/R}A)'&\rightarrow&(X\times_{X/R}A)'\\
&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
&&(X\times_{X/R}A)&\rightarrow&A\\
&&\downarrow&&\downdownarrows\\
R&\rightrightarrows&X&\xrightarrow{p}&X/R\\
&&&f\searrow&\ \downarrow g\\
&&&&Z
\end{array}
$$
where $(X\times_{X/R}A)\times_A(X\times_{X/R}A)'$ exists as $(X\times_{X/R}A)\rightarrow A$ is also a universal effective epimorphism.

Notice the two morphisms $(X\times_{X/R}A)\times_A(X\times_{X/R}A)'\rightrightarrows X\xrightarrow{f}Z$ are equal to
$$(X\times_{X/R}A)\times_A(X\times_{X/R}A)'\rightarrow A\rightrightarrows X/R\xrightarrow{g}Z,$$
hence equal by assumption.

As $R$ is defined by $f$, we find then that the morphisms $(X\times_{X/R}A)\times_A(X\times_{X/R}A)'\rightrightarrows X$ factor through $R$.

This shows that the morphisms
$$(X\times_{X/R}A)\times_A(X\times_{X/R}A)'\rightarrow A\rightrightarrows X/R$$ are equal.

Finally, as compositions of universal effective epimorphisms are universal effective epimorphisms, we conclude that indeed the morphisms $A\rightrightarrows X/R$ are equal. Therefore $g$ is a monomorphism.

This shows the fibre product $X/R\times_{Z}X/R\cong X/R$, thus we can apply the proposition to show that $g$ is a monomorphism ... just kidding.

Comment: very nice, thank you for working this out.

Comment: My pleasure. :)